# How can I make my radio buttons look like toggle buttons with ngFor?

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, togglebutton

This is a BuzzFeed style quiz.
My radio selections are questions that are looped through and added up to a certain number score. I can't figure out how to make them appear selected *without* the circle from the radio button.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label
          >{{ quizQuestions[0] }}
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  *ngFor="let flavor of answerSetOne">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
              <input  
              checked
              type="radio" 
              name="flavor" 
              class="btn-check" 
              ngModel [value]="flavor.num" 
              required/>
              {{ flavor.name | titlecase}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
```

When I put `data-toggle="buttons"` the radio circles disappear, but it no longer selects an option for the result.

How can I make the circles disappear to show the code *and* the user that a certain option has been selected?

This is what it looks like now when it works.
[working quiz section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yVMe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like a CSS question here. You can make them disappear with :

```
input[type=radio] {
  appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: It's also a functionality question. Besides the circles, the user wouldn't know what option they selected.

Comment: @AllisonBarnett this is also a CSS question. If you only want to style the input, then fo for the `input:checked` selector. If you need to style the `div` itself, you will probably need a [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) on the `div`